# Windows home network printer works locally, but not on network

Tags: windows, printing, network-printer, windows-networking

I have a USB printer here that is connected to a Windows XP machine (the host). This printer is shared and used by two Windows 7 machines, and one Ubuntu machine.

This setup has worked until today. Now the printer only works when printing from the host machine, not from the network. I've restarted the XP machine, but that didn't help. I can ping the host.

On the Ubuntu machine I see the following error message: Processing - Unable to connect to CIFS host...

Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

#### UPDATE

I changed the groupname and computer name for that computer, and now I can find the printer when I reinstall in on Ubuntu. However, when I print a page, I get the following error message:

```
Processing - Connection failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

So it finds the printer with correct name etc when I reinstall it, but when printing, the network name is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out HackingTool.RootKit was the problem. This morning a popup appeared from Norton Security Check (or something like that) saying that a security threat was found. As I never installed Norton, and someone else probably did this when updating another program, I removed Norton. I had Avast installed, removed that too, and replaced it with MS Security Essentials, which is my preferred AV tool for now. That found the rootkit and removed it. Then the computer appeared in the network again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it matters, but did the IP address of the host change?  I've never setup networked printers in Ubuntu but if it requires the ip address where the printer is located instead of say the host name or something, maybe it still thinks the pc is at the old ip.  Are you still able to browse files etc?  Also, are you 100% sure the ip you are pinging is the printer host and not the other computer?

Comment: For Ubuntu, that was the case with my old installation (11.04). Since about two weeks I have a completely new setup (12.04) and that uses a SMB-share. However, the other two W7 computers have the same problem. So it's not an Ubuntu issue. And the IP-address hasn't changed btw...

Comment: I updated my question!